# MethodNotAllowedHttpException thrown after user logs in and get redirected

Tags: php, post, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Was testing around and this is the behaviour: I have a page with a form, anyone can use it (no need to be logged in), when submitting you get redirected to the next one for which you need to be logged in as a user.
Here is the route:

```
        /*
    | Request Booking (POST)
    */
    Route::post('/booking/request-pay-booking', array(
        'as' => 'booking-request-pay-booking-post',
        'uses' => 'BookingController@postRequestPayBooking'
    ));
```

Everything works as long as you are already logged in BEFORE. If you are public when you click submit it redirects to the log in screen and once you click log in I tries to redirect to the page but I get a MethodNotAllowedHttpException thrown at me. 
I must be missing something there...

How would you handle that? Is it because it is a POST that takes me from one page to the other and the datas get lost?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably because the route is `POST` and you are redirected there with `GET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. Ended up doing something that works: created a new function that I redirect too when submitting the form, in this one I validate datas and store in a session the inputs. When the VALIDATE passes I redirect to the next view in which I extract the infos from the session and now even if I go through login screen it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you make any redirection you use for the path you want to redirect GET method, so you should probably change for some route from for example:

```
Route::post(
```

to

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST']
```

So in case you make redirection to the route you put in the question you should change it into:

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/booking/request-pay-booking', array(
    'as' => 'booking-request-pay-booking-post',
    'uses' => 'BookingController@postRequestPayBooking'
));
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to change the problem now (meaning it solved one part of it). It now tries to redirect me to the page I just left (the one with the submit button) instead of the "new" one with the post datas....
My routing is nested under this:
    Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
 
 /*
 | CRSF protection group
 */
 
 Route::group(array('before' => 'csfr'), function() {
  [.......]

Comment: @commandantp It's hard to say what exactly is your another problem without full code. You should check your logic

Comment: Yes, but that's the strange thing there is nothing behind it right now. The authenticated group is a laravel basic function and the CRSF too. 
It brings me a page back... ummmm...would you have an idea for a way around?

Comment: @commandantp Without putting your code into question I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: no worries, if you look below we might have a lead on the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not logged in before. Your request is not successfully done, and the login screen shows.

The request i.e. to your /booking/request-pay-booking url will be stored in the session, if you are using redirect intended within your login function then it is returning you to the page you requested before you logged in, after you have successfully logged in.

But not via POST via GET instead.

To overcome this allow both GET and POST to this route.

As you are only handling the request via post, allow for both methods. So post data should be stored somewhere else, for example; Session.

Store data within Session

```
Session::put('data', $data);
```

Get data from the Session

```
$data = Session::get('data');
```

If you do this then the method is not relying on a certain method to be used then use Marcin's solution;

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/booking/request-pay-booking', array(
    'as' => 'booking-request-pay-booking-post',
    'uses' => 'BookingController@requestPayBooking'
));
```

Small change as the method handles both get and post change the name of the method to requestPayBooking.

Comment: Thanks. This is my redirect route inside my postSignIn function: 
    `if ($auth) {
                // Redirect to the intended page;
                return Redirect::intended('/');
            } else {`
It doesn't say if it is get or post...

Comment: The redirect intended with redirect you to the url you were trying to get to, via the GET method.

Comment: Oh! So it will go back to the last GET and obviously it won't work out since it needs arguments. How can I allow POST and GET?

Comment: By handling each of the Routes separately. Or by instead of posting your data via post use the Session to store the data and use the data when you can, by using Marcin's method as both method will be handled but only one function will be written.

Comment: Ok thanks, will try with the session. No clue how to do that yet, I will look for a tutorial :-) thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry dumb question but where/when can I put the session::put ? In a function or in the form...

Comment: It is up to you. But it can be do be from anywhere

Comment: Ummm ok trying something will see

Comment: so stuck... so I think the problem is that I have the Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), before my route meaning I need to store the session before routing. How can I do that? :O I just don;t understand where I can use the Session::put to actually have something happening...

Comment: Session will persist before/after you login. Auth filter only checks if you are logged in to the laravel app. Thats why i say you can place it in your view or in your controller.

Comment: Oh ok, and is it normal that I cannot see it in the ressources of the page (using chrome for example) ?

Comment: Pfiou thank you so much for your help! I am getting there slowly haha... OK LAST one, How do I get to put my inputs value in the session, if I set the session in the view..? Say I have <input name="test" value="5">  and just before I close my form I want to add that value to the session, can I do {{ Session::put('input_test', Input::get('test')) }}.  Just tried it returned something NULL after. Thanks!

Comment: You dont have to put it in to a input field just put it straight into the session in your view i.e. Session::put('input_test','5')

Comment: yes I know but the value of the input field is determined by what the users choses or writes...