# Laravel : MethodNotAllowedHttpException thrown after user Logs In

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I read the solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142589/methodnotallowedhttpexception-thrown-after-user-logs-in-and-get-redirected) question but it did not solve my problem. So I am writing a new one.

I have a page in which  **user** writes a review about a product. The **user** needs to be **logged in** to write a review.

My controller action that handles the review looks like this:

```
public function postWriteReview(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [ 
        'review' => 'required|min:5',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();

    $review = new Review([
        'review' => $request->input('review'),
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'product_id' => $id,
        'rating' => 2.5
    ]);

    $review->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Review Recorded. Thank You for the Review');
}
```

And my routes file looks like:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('section.home');
})->name('home');

Route::get('products', [
    'uses' =>  'ProductController@getIndex',
    'as' => 'section.products'
]);

Route::get('products/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getProduct',
    'as' => 'section.product'
]);

Route::post('write/{id}',[
    'uses' =>  'ProductController@postWriteReview',
    'as' => 'write',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);

Auth::routes();
```

### Problem

- Everything works fine when a user is **already logged in** and submits a review.
- When the user has not logged in already, submitting the review redirects him to the login page. When the user logs in successfully, he is redirected to the previous page but **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** is thrown.

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142589/methodnotallowedhttpexception-thrown-after-user-logs-in-and-get-redirected) question's answer, I tried  allowing both GET and POST to this route like:

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'],'write/{id}',[
    'uses' =>  'ProductController@postWriteReview',
    'as' => 'write',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

With this in place, the **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** is gone but the user is redirected to the homepage instead of proceeding further and saving the review in the database.

- What is causing this?
- What is the possible solution?

Laravel Version: 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Put an auth guard in your postWriteReview() method, so if an unauthorized user submits a review, they are redirected to the homepage right away. Ideally, you should put auth middleware on the page where they are able to write the review, and if they are not an authorized user, then don't display the review form. That way, they don't waste their time writing a review when they are not logged in that they cannot post.

```
public function postWriteReview(Request $request, $id)
{
if (!Auth::check()) return redirect()->route('home');

    $this->validate($request, [ 
        'review' => 'required|min:5',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();

    $review = new Review([
        'review' => $request->input('review'),
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'product_id' => $id,
        'rating' => 2.5
    ]);

    $review->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Review Recorded. Thank You for the Review');
}
```